# Breadth first links crawling

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Let's say I have a website with:

- http://example.com/home that has links to /page1, /page2, /page3
- http://example.com/page1 that has links to /page2368
- http://example.com/page2 that has links to /page41
- http://example.com/page2368 that has links to /page999990, /page999991, ..., /page999999

Now when using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def visit(url, recursion=0):
    links = getpage_and_retrieve_ahref_links(url)   # using beautifulsoup
    for link in links:
        if recursion < 10:         # limit recursion to 10 
            visit(link, recursion+1)

visit('http://example.com/home')
```

it will visit /home, /page1, /page2368, /page999990, /page999991, ..., /page999999 before even visiting /page2. In short, it's doing a depth-first traversing instead of (what I want) a breadth-first traversing.

**How to modify the previous code to do a breadth-first visit, i.e. all `visit` with `calls recursion=1` first, then `visit` calls with `recursion=2`, etc.?**

It should visit /home, /page1, /page2, /page3, /page2368, /page41, /page999990, etc. in this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a double-ended queue ([`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) in Python) to do the breadth-first search by appending links from n+1 level after links from n level.

```
from collections import deque

def bfs_visit(url, max_level=10):
    queue = deque([url])
    level = 0

    while queue and level < max_level:
        url = queue.popleft()
        visit_no_recur(url)  # only visits the page

        links = get_links(url)  # get links, maybe parse the result of last statement
        queue.append(links)
        level += 1 

bfs_visit('http://example.com/home')
```

On the given example, the queue will look like this:

```
['/home']  
    => popleft /home (i.e. the next page to be visited is /home)
    => add new links on right
['/page1', '/page2', '/page3'] 
    => popleft /page1
    => add new links on right
['/page2', '/page3', '/page2368']
    => popleft /page2
    => add new links on right
['/page3', '/page2368', '/page41']
    => popleft /page3
['/page2368', '/page41']
    => popleft /page2368
    => add new links on right
['/page41', '/page999990', '/page999991', ..., '/page999999']
    ...
```